# Is there any search engine that searches more indepth web?

Tags: search

Is there any search engine that fills the gap where the normal search engines returns zero results.

Occasionally I need to do a search containing special characters. Like for instance searching for the gnu building configure parameter "--with-newlib". It is not rare for google to completely destroying the specific string och characters I want to search for and turning up with nothing or nothing useful.

It is really annoying knowing your desired search term is really common but not being able to return a single result.

edit:
google code search seems to have it's uses but it doesn't search the web at all. I would much rather have highly ranked web pages containing the search term when I'm searching the web.

Answer (score 2):

Google does not store those characters for normal search as they are rare and don't provide much benefit to mainstream search vs the cost of storing the extra info.

For what you want, try [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch).

Answer (score 1):

I like using [Clusty](http://clusty.com), it returns search results in groups (clusters) that I find easier to whittle down than raw Google results.

See [a search using your example, `--with-newlib`](http://clusty.com/search?v:file=viv_1066@20:YqbdID&v:frame=list&v:state=(root(N454(N442)))|N454&id=N454&action=list&sw=|Gcc|Gcc||Gcc|&sec=1233360080&)

Comment: Wow!  Nice site!  I'll definitely be trying this out for a few days.  =]

Answer (score 1):

You can Google for strings such as "--with-newlib" using some encoding tricks. You may have to experiment with them to find the combination that works for you. You will need an HTML encoding table or calculator, as specified in ISO 10646, ISO 8879, ISO 8859-1.

First up, encoded using HTML number, e.g., search for (quotes important):

```
"&#45;&#45;with&#45;newlib"
```

Encoded using HTML name, e.g., search for:

```
"&amp;"
```

Encoded cascades - run search, note what query box returns, click the search button again, repeat

```
"&#38;&#35;38;&#38;&#35;35;57;"
```

Another example search cascade, this time querying for ampersand encodings in KML files

```
"&#38;&#35;38;" doctype:xml
```

You can also query for URI encodings in a similar way, e.g., 50-100%

```
"50..100&#38;&#35;37;"
```

or more simply

```
"100&#37;26"
```

Bottom line, all of these searches involve creating an artificial query that searches for the encoded character so that Google doesn't simply strip it out. Sometimes this works, and sometimes this doesn't. You should almost always wrap your search with quotes and you should also experiment running these queries using the verbatim filter available under Search Tools --> All Results --> Verbatim after first running a search.

One tip - select and copy your original query since Google converts HTML encodings to presentation format after running the search and you may want to paste it in and modify the query before running it again.